# How to make "dictionary" with shell functions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "ARGUMENTS COUNT : " $#
echo "ARGUMENTS LIST  : " $*

dictionary=`awk '{ print $1 }'`

function()
{
   for i in dictionary
   do
      for j in $*
      do
         if [ $j = $i ]
         then
            ;
         else
            append
         fi
      done
   done
}

append()
{
   ls $j > dictionary1.txt
}

function
```

I need using unix shell functions make "dictionary". For example: I write in arguments default word, example `hello`. Then my function checks the file `dictionary1` if that word is existing in the file. If not - append that word in file, if it's already exist - do nothing.

For some reason, my script does not work. When I start my script, it waits for something and that's it.

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: The awk command is waiting for input and blocks.

Comment: If you just want to check whether a given word has been seen before, a bash associative array can do that in memory -- no files needed. If you want storage on-disk, by contrast, sorting your inputs will allow a bisection-based search algorithm, which is **vastly** faster than what you're doing now.

Comment: BTW, wrt narrow tactical issues with the solution, see http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: As another aside, `function` is a keyword in ksh-compatible shells (which bash aspires to be), so you can't safely use it as the name of a shell function.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I know that. But such a requirements of exercise.

Comment: Include your requirements in the question! Otherwise we don't know what's being done for a lack of knowledge of alternatives, and what's being done because it was explicitly asked of you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I mentioned that. I wrote: "I need using unix shell functions make "dictionary""

Comment: @EdgarasAlšauskas, umm. What part of any of my comments say you can't or shouldn't use shell functions? What I'm arguing is that you should implement those shell functions *differently* -- either have them create an in-memory associative array, or have them maintain sorted files (which you'll notice is how the real `dict` file on UNIX is stored, because it allows far faster access).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No one. But You said: "Include your requirements in the question!". I have written the requirements in the question - I need to use functions.

Comment: How is "such a requirements of exercise" meaningful if I didn't tell you to do anything that breaks that requirement? I didn't tell you not to use functions, I told you not to name your function `function`.

Comment: Normally a dictionary isn't just a list of words but instead a list of pairs - the word plus the definition of that word. I see in your code you use `awk '{print $1}'` (note $1, not $0) to get the list of words as if that might be the case for your application too. Is it? [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input (i.e. "dictionary" file contents) and expected output so we can best help you.

Answer (score 3):

An implementation that tries to care about both performance and correctness might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT sh; sh does not support [[ ]] or <(...)

addWords() {
  local tempFile dictFile
  tempFile=$(mktemp dictFile.XXXXXX) || return
  dictFile=$1; shift

  [[ -e "$dictFile" ]] || touch "$dictFile" || return

  sort -um "$dictFile" <(printf '%s\n' "$@" | sort -u) >"$tempFile"
  mv -- "$tempFile" "$dictFile"
}

addWords myDict beta charlie delta alpha
addWords myDict charlie zulu
cat myDict
```

...has a final dictionary state of:

```
alpha
beta
charlie
delta
zulu
```

...and it rereads the input file only *once* for each `addWords` call (no matter how many words are being added!), not once per word to add.

Comment: Yes, it works perfeclty, but for me it's too complicated... :(

Comment: If you learn the practices and idioms that currently look "too complicated", they won't be too complicated anymore. If your teachers don't want you to be learning on your own or from supplemental resources, then you shouldn't be here at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But first of all, I need to be good with basics.

Comment: Everything is easy once you understand it well....I plan to get there someday. ;)

Comment: By calling a second `sort -u` on the short list of new words and assuming the old file contents were already sorted you could use a merge so speed this up a lot, yes? That's kinda slick, Charles.

Comment: Why use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` why not just `#!/usr/bin/bash`?

Comment: @Gox, that way it uses the PATH to find the version of bash to use. That's important for folks on MacOS where the vendor-provided one is ancient 3.2, whereas something like Nixpkgs or MacPorts or Homebrew (listed in my personal, very-opinionated order-of-preference) is frequently used to install a modern release.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove your `dictionary=awk...` line (as mentioned it's blocking waiting for input) and simply grep your dictionary file for each argument, something like the below :

```
for i in "$@"
do
  if ! grep -qow "$i" dictionary1.txt
  then
    echo "$i" >> dictionary1.txt
  fi
done
```

Comment: Running one `grep` per possible word addition? That's ridiculously expensive, compared to just doing a single merge sort between a (sorted) list of the existing words and a (sorted) list of the new words. (Keep the storage in sort order, and you only need to sort the new words -- presumably the shorter sublist).

Comment: @Charles I think this was the simplest solution , agree it's not the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't name a function "function".
- Don't read in and walk through the whole file - all you need is to know it the word is there or not. `grep` does that.
- `ls` lists files. You want to send a word to the file, not a filename. use `echo` or `printf`.
- `sh` isn't `bash`. Use `bash` unless there's a clear reason not to, and the only reason is because it isn't available.

Try this:

```
#! /bin/env bash
checkWord() {
 grep -qm 1 "$1" dictionary1.txt ||
    echo "$1" >> dictionary1.txt
}

for wd
do checkWord "$wd"
done
```

If that works, you can add more structure and error checking.

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
awk -v words="$*" '
BEGIN {
    while ( (getline word < "dictionary1.txt") > 0 ) {
        dict[word]++
    }
    close("dictionary1.txt")

    split(words,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        word = tmp[i]
        if ( !dict[word]++ ) {
            newWords = newWords word ORS
        }
    }

    printf "%s", newWords >> "dictionary1.txt"
    exit
}'
```